# Where I can find out online patent trading platform for me to sell my patent to those potential buyers who come from global testing industry

Tags: trade

I have national patent granted since June, 2022; I would like to to sell it to the potential buyer who come from instrument manufacturer or global testing industry. Could you share where I can find out an online patent trading platform for me to sell my patent to those potential buyers who come from global testing industry e.g. SGS or global instrument manufacturer, or global supply-chain business sector which need chemical test to comply with regulatory safety standard before delivering finished products to US and EU countries' markets? Thanks, Francis

Comment: I have no knowledge of an online patent trading platform. Since patents are hardly commodities, I kind of doubt there is one.

Comment: There are people who set themselves up as patent brokers. They can proactively look for companies that might benefit from patents in particular industries. I would search for patent brokers.

Comment: Hi George, Thanks you for your reply. I have found out few US patent broker; they charged 20% of the selling price from me in case they made a deal with the potential buyer successfully otherwise they will charge me USD 2500 service fee but they don't guarantee they can find out buyer. Therefore, I doubt these private patent brokers for such and looking for an online patent trading platform for seller and buyer to make a deal by themselves directly. May you share your experience and your network where I can find out such online patent trading platform in USA? Many thanks

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your sharing.